# CakePHP Eclipse support (intellisense and coding standards)

Tags: php, eclipse, cakephp

I've been looking (quite unsuccessfully) for a plugin to help make CakePHP development in Eclipse more efficient.

I'm after a plugin or config file for CakePHP coding standards (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html)

And something that will let me jump between Models/Controllers/Views seamlessly as well as some sort of intellisense support.  (I don't want to have to include var $modelname in the controllers)

I found this for switching models http://opencakefile.sourceforge.net/  however after following the instructions, none of the short cuts it suggest work as well as not seeing 'CakePHP' on the menu bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On a brief look the `opencakefile` plug-in only adds to the tool bar rather than the menu.

Comment: that's why I switched to netbeans ...

Comment: Thanks Greg, yeah it appears I do have the cake icon in eclipse, but it doesn't do anything sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have nice support for Cake in Eclipse you will need to:

- include `var $modelname` in the controllers
- Use the opencakefile (Yes it is hard to get running but it will work)
- For Helpers i can suggest the ["ThisHelper"](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/leoden/2012/03/28/eclipse_code_completion_in_views_using_this)

The "ThisHelper" is a nice idea I've been using for 2 years now. It will provide auto-complete support for Helpers' methods in views.

Now the way that Eclipse is built and the way CakePhp 2.x is built don't quite add up so that you have full IDE features for Cake with Eclipse.

Other IDE options are:

- NetBeans
- [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) (Doesn't quite go that far since it is Eclipse-based)
- [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) via the [CakeStormPlugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7277?pr=phpStorm) (I've tried it and it is great)
- [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) again with the [CakeStormPlugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7277?pr=phpStorm)

Just keep in mind that WebStorm is more Front-End oriented.
To my regret there is still not adequate support for Cake in Eclipse, however with Cake3.x this should change. :)) Currently I am exploring the idea of switching totally to PHPStorm.

I've had my fair share of trying to get Eclipse configured better for CakePHP, but there isn't much that one could do. I am actually using [Eclipse PDT](http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/pdt/) from Zend (i.e. the community version of [ZendStudio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/)). Hope this helps.